# Toggle menu with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a sidebar with toggle menus of companies. I get the companies data from api and print it out. And each company has same two subtitle "documents" and "add new document".

I use ng-repeat for printing all the companies to sidebar. And i couldn't find any solution to toggle these menus.

Last thing i found is this:

```
    <li data-ng-click="toggleMenu($event)" ng-repeat="company in companies" >
       <a class="nav-submenu" data-toggle="nav-submenu" href="#">
           <span class="sidebar-mini-hide">{{company.name}}</span>
       </a>

       <ul>
          <li>
            <a data-ui-sref="{{company.id}}" data-ui-sref-active="active">
                <i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>Company's Documents
            </a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a data-ui-sref="{{company.id}}" data-ui-sref-active="active">
               <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Add New Document
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
  </li>
```

Here is the Js Code:

```
   $scope.toggleMenu = function($event){

     $($event.currentTarget).toggleClass('open');
     $($event.currentTarget).siblings().removeClass('open');

   };
```

But this code causes menu to close whenever i click on the "add new document" or "documents" of any company.

Any help would be great for me !

Thanks,
Burak

Comment: You can add `ngClick` for the actual links and control the `open` class using `ngClass` (And a custom flag on the `company` element in the `ngRepeat` loop like `company.isOpen` for example) - You should avoid as much as possible uglifying your angular code with jQuery

Comment: Can you show me an example ? I also feel that i shouldn't use jquery codes but i couldn't find any solution right now :(

Comment: Try removing `data-ng-click="toggleMenu($event)"` and instead add `ng-class="{open: company.isOpen}"`, next add `ng-click="company.isOpen = !company.isOpen"`  on the `<a class="nav-submenu" data-toggle="nav-submenu" href="#">` element (I can't post it as an answer because i'm not sure if it will work)

Comment: It actually works man, thanks a lot. But there is one problem left. When i clicked company1 toggle works, then i tried to click company2 and company1's toggle doesn't close. Would be great if you can find a solution to it too :)

Comment: I have added an answer with a new solution since you confirmed my last suggestion was partially working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote in the comment: *You should avoid as much as possible uglifying your angular code with jQuery*.

I suggested the following as an alternative:

```
<li ng-class="{open: company.isOpen}" ng-repeat="company in companies" >
   <a ng-click="company.isOpen = !company.isOpen" class="nav-submenu" data-toggle="nav-submenu" href="#">
       <span class="sidebar-mini-hide">{{company.name}}</span>
   </a>
```

But as you correctly say, it won't close to menu if you're clicking on another company menu.

So here is a similar, but different approach:

```
<li ng-class="{open: currentOpen.companyId == company.id}" ng-repeat="company in companies" >
   <a ng-click="currentOpen.companyId = currentOpen.companyId == company.id ? null : company.id" class="nav-submenu" data-toggle="nav-submenu" href="#">
       <span class="sidebar-mini-hide">{{company.name}}</span>
   </a>
```

This will store the **company id** when you click on it in an object: `$scope.currentOpen.companyId`, and will add the `open` class if it matched to the same company id inside the `ngRepeat` loop.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/jsv2q4bm/

Comment: dude it is really close, but still not closing other menus. can you provide another solution ?

Comment: @burakkesepara Have you changed both the `ng-class` and `ng-click` to the ones on my second example?

Comment: yes. i copied and pasted whole code that you wrote. now, i can open up one company's menu but can't close it. also when i open other company's menu, first company's menu is not closing.

Comment: Oh, so i have edited the `ng-click` that will remove the current company id if it's the same, which should close the menu

Comment: now i can close menu that i opened before, but still not closing other menus :(

Comment: I lost my internet connection due to a storm... Will check it when it's back (sent from my mobile phone)

Comment: @burakkesepara Can you tried this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jsv2q4bm/)? I think what's missing is setting a default value to to `currentOpen.companyId` - I added it from the controller, you can also do it from the view using `ng-init="currentOpen.companyId = null"` on the parent `<ul>`

Comment: And that's the answer : ng-init="currentOpen.companyId = null" !